# Attached/ calculus about local minimum and maximum

Tags: calculus

[image]

I got couple questions with the same issue, could anyone tell me how to know if it was local minimum, local maximum or neither ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Theorem. A critical point $x=c$ is a local minimum point of $f$ if there is are intervals $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ such that $f'$ is negative on $(a,c)$ and positive on $(c,b)$.

This is sometimes called the First Derivative Test. An analagous result holds for local max's.

The derivative is $6t^{-1/3}+1$. Consider the critical point $t=0$ (it is a critical point because the original function is not differentiable here). The derivative is negative just to the left of $t=0$ and positive to the right, i.e., $t=0$ is a local minimum point.  Try the other critical point $t=-216$ (the root of the derivative) using this method...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Evaluate the second derivative of the function at the critical points. If it is negative, it is a local max. Positive, local min. $0$ is indeterminant.

Comment: In the case second derivative is $0$ we could have local max, local min, or neither.

Comment: Why do I need to take the second derivative ? and can't I determine by just checking their signs now ?

Comment: The first derivative tells you the points where the slope of the function is $0$, but it doesn't tell you at that point, if the function is concave up or concave down. The second derivative gives you that information.

Comment: you can just look for the sign of the first derivative on an interval to the right of $x=0$ and on an interval to its left.  For instance the sign combination -,+ would indicate local min.

Comment: @TomCruise So I end up having zero as minimum and -216 as maximum, right ? and how to know if it is neither?

Comment: @TomCruise I think no, because when you try to take numbers on the left of ( -216 )) I will end up having a positive and the left negative. Nevertheless, for the ( zero ) on the left as I said is negative and on the right positive. Am I right?

Comment: @user157908 - Make sure you have the correct critical points. You need to solve for $t$, where $g'(t) = 0$

Comment: @user157908 yes you are right!