# critical points - calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = 5x^{1/5} − x $$

$$f^\prime (x)= x^{-4/5} -1 $$

The question is:

> Find the $x$ values of all of the critical points. Enter your answers as a comma separated list.

As far as I know that the answer is 1 but every time I input it it says wrong :( could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative is $0$ at $x=1$ and $x=-1$. In addition, the function is defined at $x=0$ but the derivative is not (or, depending on taste, is infinite). So according to the definitions in many calculus books (check yours) we also have a critical point at $x=0$.

**Added:** If you are using the same resource as when you 
asked [this question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847891/attached-calculus-about-local-minimum-and-maximum) your course would say there is a critical point at $x=0$.

Comment: I added the f(x) now, and I thought of -1 but when you substitute the -1 in the f'(x) you will not get zero.

Comment: We have $(-1)^{-4/5}=((-1)^4)^{-1/5}=1^{-1/5}=1$.